Можно ли изменить этот шаблон от Firebase на свой или на свою страницу чтобы отправляло?
При регистрации, через Firebase, отправляется письмо на эл почту для подтверждения. При переходе по ссылке, открывается окно c готовым шаблоном:

Можно ли поменять переадресацию на свой сайт или изменить этот шаблон, условно скруглить края, поменять текст?
